# Simple Counter Function Not Working in Animation Nodes

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I'm using the following script from the blender documentation to try and create a time based counter:

```
import bpy

counter = 0


def run_10_times():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    if counter == 10:
        return None
    return 0.1


bpy.app.timers.register(run_10_times)
```

However when I this I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "script: 'My Script'", line 25, in run_10_times
> NameError: name 'counter' is not defined

What am I doing wrong here?
Here's a picture of my node setup.

[image]

Here's an example of using a script variable from the animation nodes documenation:
[image]

Comment: So you want to increment your counter every 10th of a second until it hits 10 ? Are you planning to use this counter for Animation using the timeline ?

Comment: @Gorgious I'm planning on using it in an animation nodes script

Comment: Would a solution using the current frame be sufficient ? (ie if you have 30 frames per second, the counter will be at 10 on frame 30)